# Understanding directory structure advice

Tags: django, configuration, structure, directory-structure

I started to create in Django sample project, first command:

`django-admin.py startproject test`

gives me:

```
- root
  - test
    - __init__.py 
    - settings.py 
    - urls.py 
    - wsgi.py 
    - manage.py
```

Now I create first app:

`python manage.py startapp foo`

it created for me folder `root/foo`

so how I should understand my `root/test` folder. Is this folder for global config of my project and nothing more? (similar to Symfony 2 app folder)

I am confused because Django docs tells:

> The inner mysite/ directory is the actual Python package for your
>   project

but `manage.py startapp foo` create app under root, not under `root/test` (mysite equivalent)

**[EDIT]**

Two commands:

```
python manage.py startapp app
```

and:

```
django-admin.py startapp app
```

gives me app inside project root, not under `root/name_of_generated_project`

Django 1.4

**[EDIT] 2**

Sorry guys, my fault, now is everything ok.

**[EDIT] 3**

I want to create another project again:

`django-admin.py startproject jobeet`

my initial structure is similar to above.

Now I want to try create app (inside jobeet folder):

`django-admin.py startapp jobs`

and I end up with `jobeet/jobs` not `jobeet/jobeet/jobs`

again :/

so inside my project root I have:

```
- jobeet
- jobs
- manage.py
```

another command:

```
python manage.py startapp app
```

gives me the same result

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So let's say you create a new Django project `testproject`:

> django-admin.py startproject testproject

This creates a new project with the following minimal set of files:

```
testproject/
├── __init__.py
├── manage.py
├── settings.py
└── urls.py
```

To create a new app for your first site `mysite1` go into `testproject` directory and run:

> python manage.py startapp mysite1

which results in a new directory `mysite1` for the `mysite1` app.

I.e. with just these two commands you would arrive at this hierarchy:

```
testproject/
├── __init__.py
├── manage.py
├── mysite1
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── tests.py
│   └── views.py
├── settings.py
└── urls.py
```

Refer to the `django-admin.py` and/or `manage.py` individual commands [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/django-admin/).

In Django there is a **one-to-many** relationship between a `project` and an `app`. An app is usually one individual site component (e.g. `comments`, `ratings`), whereas a project is an organisation of several apps and can power many different sites. That's why you get the [sites framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/). In practice, one project usually serves one website, but with Django `sites` app with one project you can serve as many websites as you like, for reusability's sake.

P.S. I think creating a project simply called `test` is not a good practice because with Django unit tests at `app` level unit tests will go into a file called `tests.py` or within a folder called `tests`.

**UPDATE for Django 1.4**

As *@zeantsoi* has commented below, my answer:

> applies to Django 1.3 and prior. [Per the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4/#updated-default-project-layout-and-manage-py), beginning in 1.4, base
>   configuration files (including settings.py, urls.py, and wsgi.py) are
>   abstracted into a subdirectory titled the same name as the project.

Comment: Name test is just example, real name is different. I am sorry for this.

Comment: @drupality No problem. Hope you find my answer helpful.

Comment: I would strongly hesitate to refer to an app as "individual site" most sites will be composed of more than one app and frequently the project is a single site

Comment: @John <<Most sites will be composed of more than one app>> Definitely agree. <<frequently the project is a single site>> I beg to differ: in my experience one project served > 4 different sites (different top-level domains). The Django community itself discusses how to best [split settings](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/SplitSettings) so that one project can serve several different sites, even though there is no accepted best way of doing it, yet.

Comment: I still doesnt understand which structure is correct and how to use it:/

Comment: type these commands: `mkdir myroot; cd myroot; django-admin startproject test; cd test; ./manage.py startapp foo`  This should get you the correct starting structure.  @JosvicZammit and I are just disagreeing about semantics.  A project should have 1 more more apps, and a project represents one or more sites (sites being actual url's for the most part)

Comment: @JosvicZammit, the depicted directory structure, by default, only applies to Django 1.3 and prior. [Per the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.4/#updated-default-project-layout-and-manage-py), beginning in 1.4, base configuration files (including settings.py, urls.py, and wsgi.py) are abstracted into a subdirectory titled the same name as the project.

Answer (score 2):

"test" is the top level of your project.  I've never used symphony 2 so I can't comment on that, but it seems like you have a grasp on it.  The files that live in there are basically all global config files.  Inside your "test" folder you should also have one or more app folders.  Inside these app folders live the apps specific models, views, urls, etc.

It seems you've got something a little wrong your `foo` app should live in root/test/foo not root/foo.

Now in my projects I tend to have things like a virtualenv folder live in the root dir, but you definitively shouldn't have apps at that level (it just won't work)

Comment: all startproject does is create a directory named by the parameter you pass it and put some starting files you'll need in it.  All startapp does is create a directory within your current one and put the files that most every app will use inside it.  If you don't cd into your project between runing the commands you're going to create the wrong structure.  There really isn't any magic going on within startapp and startproject, it's just creating a basic structure

Answer (score 1):

manage.py doesn't provide a startproject command - that's usually a django-admin command. I'd check which manage.py you're executing, and ideally, use the manage.py from the project directory you've created.

Comment: I am using Django 1.4, I am inside my project root, command: python manage.py (proper manage.py) startapp app, created for another app in root, so it is default behaviour :/